unwanted subdivision on header of table
I have the following document and I need to reflect the table in which one of the columns needed to be subdivided for some check marks. The problem is that I have tried consequently due to \hline after the last column and its extension subdivided all columns unwantedly
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pifont}   % for checkmark symbols
\usepackage{multirow} % for multi-row cells
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

%==============Begin Document
    
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Comparison of ML-based workload prediction studies}
\label{tab:comparison}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|p{0.18\textwidth}|c|c|c|c|c|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
% Main header row
\textbf{} & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{Method and Technique} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Predicted Factor}} & \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Dataset} \\

% Sub-header row for Predicted Factor, leave other columns untouched
\hline
& & & \textbf{CPU} & \textbf{Mem.} & \textbf{BW} & \textbf{Disk} & \textbf{Req.} & & \\ 
\hline

% Regression section
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Regression}}} 
& [13] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAPE & Google \\ 
& [14] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MSE & RUBiS \\ 
& [15] & LR, RR, ARDR, EN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & RMSE & Bitbrains \\ 
& [48] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & MAE, MSE, MAPE, R2 & Google, Bitbrains, PlanetLab \\ 
\hline

% Classification section
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Classification}}} 
& [4] & NN & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MSE & NASA, Saskatchewan \\ 
& [5] & GRU & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & Google, Alibaba \\ 
& [16] & SVM & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & RMSE, MAE & Google \\ 
\hline

% Deep Learning section
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Deep Learning}}} 
& [17] & NN & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & \ding{51} & RMSE & Self-made \\ 
& [18] & LSTM & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & PlanetLab \\ 
& [19] & CNN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAE & Google \\ 
\hline

% Additional rows for Deep Learning
%& [20] & BiLSTM & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MAPE & Alibaba \\

\end{tabular}%
} % end resizebox
\end{table*}

\end{document}

I also have tried following setup to full control but did not work:

Only "Predicted Factor": The \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Predicted Factor}} in the header subdivides only the "Predicted Factor" column. Each factor (CPU, Memory, BW, Disk, Req.) gets its own dedicated column within the "Predicted Factor" section.
Other Columns Merged: For columns like "Metric" and "Dataset," we
used \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} in the header row to keep them as single
columns and prevent unwanted splitting.

\begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Comparison of ML-based workload prediction studies}
\label{tab:comparison}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|p{0.18\textwidth}|c|c|c|c|c|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{Ref} & \textbf{Method and Technique} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Predicted Factor}} & \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Dataset} \\ \hline
& & & \textbf{CPU} & \textbf{Mem.} & \textbf{BW} & \textbf{Disk} & \textbf{Req.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \hline

% Regression section
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Regression}}} 
& [13] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAPE & Google \\ 
& [14] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MSE & RUBiS \\ 
& [15] & LR, RR, ARDR, EN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & RMSE & Bitbrains \\ 
& [48] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & MAE, MSE, MAPE, R2 & Google, Bitbrains, PlanetLab \\ \hline

% Classification section
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Classification}}} 
& [4] & NN & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MSE & NASA, Saskatchewan \\ 
& [5] & GRU & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & Google, Alibaba \\ 
& [16] & SVM & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & RMSE, MAE & Google \\ \hline

% Deep Learning section
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Deep Learning}}} 
& [17] & NN & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & \ding{51} & RMSE & Self-made \\ 
& [18] & LSTM & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & PlanetLab \\ 
& [19] & CNN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAE & Google \\ 
\hline

% Additional rows for Deep Learning
%& [20] & BiLSTM & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MAPE & Alibaba \\

\end{tabular}%
} % end resizebox
\end{table*}

my current output is this:


my desired output is the following:



Use \cline for lines spanning some columns only.
Better define a command \YES that expands to whatever symbol you want to use for the check marks.
You probably want to replace the hard-coded references like [21] by \cite commands that refer to bibliographic entries.


\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pifont}   % for checkmark symbols
\newcommand\YES{\ding{51}}%
\usepackage{multirow} % for multi-row cells
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox
\usepackage{lipsum}   % dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[ht]
  \caption{Comparison of ML-based workload prediction studies}
  \label{tab:comparison}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} % spread the lines a bit
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Ref}}
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method and Technique}}
    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Predicted Factor}}
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Metric}}
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dataset}} \\
  \cline{4-8}
    & & & CPU & Mem. & BW & Disk & Req. & & \\
  \hline
      \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\textbf{Regression}}}  
    & [13] & SVR & \YES & \YES & & & & MAPE & Google \\
  \cline{2-10}
    & [14] & SVR & \YES & \YES & & & & MSE & RUBiS \\ 
  \cline{2-10}
    & [15] & LR, RR, ARDR, EN, GRU & \YES & \YES & \YES & \YES & & RMSE & Bitbrains \\ 
  \cline{2-10}
    & [48] & SVR & \YES & \YES & \YES & \YES & & MAE, MSE, MAPE, R2 & Google, Bitbrains, PlanetLab \\ 
  \hline
      \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\textbf{Classification}}} 
    & [4]  & NN  & \YES & & \YES & & & MSE & NASA, Saskatchewan \\ 
  \cline{2-10}
    & [5]  & GRU & \YES & & & & & MSE & Google, Alibaba \\ 
  \cline{2-10}
    & [16] & SVM & \YES & \YES & & & & RMSE, MAE & Google \\
  \cline{2-10}
    & [17] & NN  & \YES & \YES & \YES & & & Self-made & Self-collected \\
  \hline
      \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\textbf{Deep Learning}}} 
    & [18] & LSTM& \YES & & & & & MSE & PlanetLab \\ 
  \cline{2-10}
    & [19] & DL  & \YES & & & & & MAPE, RMSE & PlanetLab \\ 
  \cline{2-10}
    & [20] & GRU & \YES & & & & & MSE & Google, Alibaba \\
  \cline{2-10}
    & [21] & CNN, GRU & \YES & \YES & & \YES & & MAE & Google \\
  \cline{2-10}
    & [22] & BiGRU & \YES & & & & & MAE, RMSE, MAPE & Google, Alibaba, Bitbrains \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table*}

\lipsum

\end{document}


+1. :-) A minor detail: The \rotatebox macro is defined in the graphicx package (which is loaded automatically by the rotating package).

@Mico Thanks, corrected.

This solution fits me well. :) I also just learned about \newcommand\YES{\ding{50}} and I could put many symbols instead of tick !!

My main recommendation would be to switch to a tabularx environment, to make it unnecessary to have to resort to the \resizebox sledgehammer. In addition, I wouldn't use bold-facing for the material in the header row and in the first column.

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\rotatebox' macro
\usepackage{multirow} % for '\multirow' macro
\usepackage{pifont}   % for '\ding' macro
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%  for use in the first column
   \begingroup
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}
   \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}
   \endgroup}

\begin{document} 
  
\begin{table*} % "[ht]" has no effect
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}      % default: 6pt

\caption{Comparison of ML-based workload prediction studies}
\label{tab:comparison}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{%
    | c | l | p{0.19\textwidth} | *{5}{c|} X | X |}
\hline
 & Ref & Method and Technique 
 & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Predicted Factor} 
 & Metric & Dataset \\ 
\cline{4-8}
& & & CPU & Mem. & BW & Disk & Req. & & \\ 
\hline

% Regression section
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Regression}} 
& [13] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAPE & Google \\ 
& [14] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MSE & RUBiS \\ 
& [15] & LR, RR, ARDR, EN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & RMSE & Bitbrains \\ 
& [48] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & MAE, MSE, MAPE, R2 & Google, Bitbrains, PlanetLab \\ \hline

% Classification section
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
    \mytab{Classi-\\fication}}} 
& [4] & NN & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MSE & NASA, Saskatchewan \\ 
& [5] & GRU & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & Google, Alibaba \\ 
& [16] & SVM & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & RMSE, MAE & Google \\ \hline

% Deep Learning section
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
    \mytab{Deep\\Learning}}} 
& [17] & NN & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & \ding{51} & RMSE & Self-made \\ 
& [18] & LSTM & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & PlanetLab \\ 
& [19] & CNN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAE & Google \\ 
\hline

% Additional rows for Deep Learning
%& [20] & BiLSTM & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MAPE & Alibaba \\

\end{tabularx}

\end{table*}

\end{document}


Here's another alternative to consider.
The booktabs package observes that most lines in a table add ink without really making the table easier to understand.  I've removed nearly all of them.  You may want a few back (especially between the three method types), but it will be easier to tell with the full table.
Since your desired output doesn't have any linebreaks within cells, there's no reason for the p type column.  You can also consider whether you want an X type column (see other answer) or switch to a tabular* (see What is the difference between tabular, tabular* and tabularx environments?).  If you're truly pressed for space, you can consider manually breaking some of the longer lines --- see row 4 below, which was solely responsible for expanding its column.
(Note that "[17] NN" moves from "Classification" to "Deep Learning" in your images.  I also agree with the suggestion of defining a macro for \ding{51}.)
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow} % for '\multirow' macro
\usepackage{pifont}   % for '\ding' macro

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document} 

\begin{table*}
\caption{Comparison of ML-based workload prediction studies}
\label{tab:comparison}

\begin{tabular}{ l l l *{5}{c} l l }
\toprule
 \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{5em}{Method\\Type}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Ref} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{5em}{Method and\\Technique}}
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Predicted Factor} 
 & \multirow{2}{*}{Metric} & \multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){4-8}
 & & & CPU & Mem. & BW & Disk & Req. & & \\ 
\midrule

% Regression section
Regres-
& [13] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAPE & Google \\ 
sion & [14] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MSE & RUBiS \\ 
& [48] & SVR & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & MAE, MSE, MAPE, R2 & Google, Bitbrains, PlanetLab \\
& [15] & LR, RR, ARDR, & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & RMSE & Bitbrains \\ 
& & \qquad EN, GRU \\ % rows 3 and 4 swapped
\addlinespace

% Classification section
Classi-
& [4] & NN & \ding{51} & & \ding{51} & & & MSE & NASA, Saskatchewan \\ 
fication & [5] & GRU & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & Google, Alibaba \\ 
& [16] & SVM & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & RMSE, MAE & Google \\ \addlinespace

% Deep Learning section
Deep
& [17] & NN & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & \ding{51} & RMSE & Self-made \\ 
Learning & [18] & LSTM & \ding{51} & & & & & MSE & PlanetLab \\ 
& [19] & CNN, GRU & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & & & & MAE & Google \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}


